# как сделать фон background: url(); на весь экран

Tags: html, css

```
<body

<div id="main"></div>

</body>
#main {
     
background: url('https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/flat-landscape-a-beautiful-purple-colored-forest_205077-670.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    
background-position: center;
}
```

как сделать так, чтобы фон получился на весь экран?

Comment: height:100vh; для дива и тег body закройте